# Cylindrical 2D grids in FiPy

Tags: python, fipy

I have read [here](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/issues/547) that gradient calculations do not work properly for cylindrical 2D grids, because of discretization erros. Does that mean that DiffusionTerm and/or other terms in FiPy are also broken for cylindrical 2D grids? Or is it just the gradient method alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just the `.grad` method. `DiffusionTerm` doesn't use it (except with anisotropic diffusion coefficients).